# Meine vs mein Leibchen

Tags: usage

I have a older woman saying sarcastically to a young man, "It's all right, mein Leibchen, we'll think of something else." Would she say "mein" because she is speaking to a man, or would she say "meine"?

Comment: The first-person pronoun "mein" inflects for the grammatical gender of the modified noun, not of the speaker. Only the third-person pronouns do that.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, it's "Liebchen" /li:pçən/, not "Leibchen" /laɪpçən/. "Liebchen" is an old-fashioned term for "sweetheart"; "Leibchen" means "undershirt".

The ending "-chen" indicates that "Liebchen" is a diminutive. All diminutives are *grammatically neuter* in German, so it must be "mein Liebchen" (using the neuter form "mein") no matter whether it's said to a man or to a woman ("mein" is masculine or neuter, "meine" is feminine).